# Change lines colour in a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the colours of the lines in a plot including two curves and 2 vertical lines, but it has been unsuccessful. Would you mind telling me how I can change my script below to assign a specifi colour to each of the 4 lines? Thanks a lot for your help!

```
data <- data.frame(day_of_year=rep(1:5, 4), variable=c('variable1', 'variable1', 'variable1', 'variable1', 'variable1', 'variable2', 'variable2', 'variable2', 'variable2', 'variable2', 'variable3', 'variable3', 'variable3', 'variable3', 'variable3', 'variable4', 'variable4', 'variable4', 'variable4', 'variable4'), value=c(12, 21, 35, 42, 56, 1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4))

p1 <- ggplot(data=data)
p1 <- p1 + geom_line(data=data[data$variable=='variable1',], aes(x=day_of_year, y=value, colour='variable1'), size=0.5)
p1 <- p1 + geom_line(data=data[data$variable=='variable2',], aes(x=day_of_year, y=value*10, colour='variable2'), size=0.5)
p1 <- p1 + geom_vline(data=data[data$variable=='variable3',], aes(xintercept=value, colour='variable3'), linetype='dashed', size=0.5)
p1 <- p1 + geom_vline(data=data[data$variable=='variable4',], aes(xintercept=value, colour='variable4'), linetype='dashed', size=0.5)
p1 <- p1 + scale_colour_discrete(breaks=c("variable1","variable2","variable3", 'variable4'))
p1 <- p1 + labs(list(colour = "", title = "(A)", x = "Day of year", y =""))
p1 <- p1 + theme_bw()
p1 <- p1 + theme(title=element_text(size=7, face='bold', vjust=0.8, hjust = 0.5), axis.text.x=element_text(size=7), axis.text.y =element_text(size=8),legend.text=element_text(size=8),legend.title=element_text(size=8), axis.title=element_text(size=8, face='bold'))
p1 <- p1 + geom_text(x=1.5, y=50, label='fallow', size=3)
p1 <- p1 + geom_text(x=3, y=50, label='crop', size=3)
p1 <- p1 + geom_text(x=4.5, y=50, label='fallow',size=3)
p1
```

This is the graph I have for the moment with the default colours:
[image: graph]

I have tried to add the scripts below, but without success:

```
# p1 <- p1 + scale_colour_manual(values=c('red','black','dark grey','blue'))
# p1 <- p1 + scale_colour_discrete(value=c("blue", "red", "grey", 'black'))
# p1 <- p1 + scale_color_manual(value=c("#CC6666", "#9999CC", "#CC6666", "#9999CC"), breaks=c("variable1","variable2","variable3", 'variable4'))
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data on which we can run your code? That will make it easier to demonstrate how to resolve your problem. For example, paste into your question the output of `dput(d[1:20,])` to provide the first 20 rows of your data frame.

Comment: @eipi10, thank you very much for your advise, here is a reproducible example.

Comment: The `p1 <- p1 + scale_colour_manual(values=c('red','black','dark grey','blue'))` option works for me on your test data. If you change `value=` to `values=`, then `p1 + scale_color_manual(values=c("#CC6666", "#9999CC", "#CC6666", "#9999CC"), breaks=c("variable1","variable2","variable3", 'variable4'))` also works with your example. Are you sure it's not working?

Answer (score 2):

Just as for @MrFlick your code worked for me with the sample data you provided (with the exception of the `value` vs. `values` typo in two of the three attempts to change the colors).

Normally, you would just want one call to `geom_line` and then `colour=variable` would create separate lines for each level of `variable`. But here it looks like you want to do something different with each level of `variable`. In any case, here is a modification of your code to make it a bit more concise, and with `scale_colour_manual` included.

```
p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=d[d$variable=='variable1',], 
            aes(x=day_of_year, y=value, colour=variable), size=0.5) +
  geom_line(data=d[d$variable=='variable2',], 
            aes(x=day_of_year, y=value*10, colour=variable), size=0.5) +
  geom_vline(data=d[d$variable %in% c('variable3','variable4'),], 
             aes(xintercept=value, colour=variable), linetype='dashed', 
             size=0.5, show.legend=FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('red','black','dark grey','blue')) +
  labs(list(colour = "", title = "(A)", x = "Day of year", y ="")) +
  theme_bw(base_size=8) +
  theme(title=element_text(size=7, face='bold', vjust=0.8, hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=7), 
        axis.title=element_text(face='bold')) +
  geom_text(data=data.frame(x=c(1.5,3,4.5), y=50), 
            aes(x,y), label=c('Fallow','Crop','Fallow'), size=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this formatting..you can change any parameter to see how the plot changes

```
 geom_line(mapping=aes(y = y, color = y), size = 1.11) +  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "blue", size = 1.25)) +
    theme(axis.ticks = element_line(size = 5, colour = "black")) +
    scale_fill_discrete() + scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", labels = date_format("%d-%b-%Y")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c(brewer.pal(9, "Set1"), brewer.pal(9, "Set1"))) + 
    labs(colour = legend.title) + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.76))) + 
    guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3))) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=number_ticks(10)) +
    theme(text = element_text(size=20), axis.title=element_text(size=34,face="bold"),
          axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=24, angle=25),
          axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=24, angle=0))
```